# Sharing Permissions in Ruby on Rails (CanCan or CanTango?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am starting my first full jump into RoR and have been looking at CanCan for permissions. I am interested in something that can allow the following:

A User can belong to a Network, or just be a solo User.
A User may be an admin or simply a user in that Network.
Users create Events for either themselves or their Network.
A Network can controls what Event its Users can Read/Edit.

That part I can't figure out, however, is what if I want to be able to share access to a single Event with another User not in my Network. Should each event have a list of acceptable Users/Networks that can read and another for Users/Networks that can write? Would a HashTable with a User/Network and their level of permissions be best?

If there is another post feel free to direct me to it.

Answer (score 0):

CanCan definitely better than CanTango!